# Universal link does not work with webpage links

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, safari, ios-universal-links

I know there are many similar questions on this issue, and I've tried my best following many of them, but still my problem remains unsolved. Any help will be appreciated.

I have a AWS server running ASP.NET MVC, and I've placed the file apple-app-site-association under the .well-known folder (with a proper Web.config to assign the mime type). I don't think there's a misconfiguration at this part of the story, for the following reasons:

1. I look at the iPhone console log as my app installs, and it reports no error when accessing my apple-app-site-association file.
2. If I paste the link into Note, by clicking on that link it indeeds open my app directly (without prompting anything).
3. When I scan a QR code containing the link URL, it prompts for using my app to open it.

However, if I have a webpage that contains the same link using an `<a href="...">` element, as I open that webpage with Safari or Chrome, clicking on that link does not even prompt for my app; it just opens the link inside the browser. No matter how I tried, I can't make such links to open my app.

I do have problem testing my URL with the [Validation Tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/), but I cannot find out why. It simply says "Could not extract required information for application links" without any extra information that can help me identify the problem. Besides, why is that the test fails, but 2. and 3. above works? I don't get it.

Also, I did pass the test at [Branch](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/).

The URL of the link in question is an https URL, with the same domain as the webpage containing it.

One thing I should probably mention: when access that URL directly, the server will response a server-side redirect (to either App Store or Google Play depending on User-Agent). I've also tried to modify that URL so that it response a normal webpage containing client-side redirect instead, but it makes no difference. The link on my webpage still opens inside the browser instead of opening my app. In that new page with client-side redirect, it will prompt me if I want to open App Store, and if I choose no, and then drag the page down a bit, I will indeed see the option "Open in App ***" showing up (another proof that things should be right), but this is not what I want; I want to the link to directly open my app (as in, for example, Instagram etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days of more digging I finally found the answer. The problem is exactly becasue the webpage containing the link and the link URL are of the same domain. According to [this page](https://awhisper.github.io/2017/09/02/universallink/) (in Chinese though), since iOS v.9.2, universal link would open my app directly, without prompting, only if the page and the link are NOT of exactly the same domain. That means using different subdomain will also work, and it does, as I just tried.

This also suggest that one does not need to worry too much about the official [Validation Tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/); failing the test over there does not necessarily means you're doing things wrong.